# Find primefactors Java

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA programming and I am having hard time doing this lab

```
import java.util.*;

public class FindPrimes
{
   private static ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();

   //post: returns true if value is a prime number
   public static boolean isPrime(int value)
   {
      if(value < 2 || value % 2 == 0)
         return false;
      if(value == 2)
         return true;
      for (int i = 3; i * i <= value; i += 2)
         if (value % i == 0) 
            return false;
      return true;

            //temporary return so program compiles
   }

   //post:  returns the index of the first non-prime number in myList.
   //           returns -1 if all numbers are prime
   private static int findNotPrime()
   {
      for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){
         if(!isPrime(myList.get(i)))
            return i;

      }

      /*ex: [60] will return 0
            [2,30] will return 1
            [2,2,15] returns 2
            [2,2,3,5] returns -1
      */
      return -1;        //temporary return so program compiles
   }

   //post:  returns the smallest factor of a number
   private static int findSmallestFactor(int num)
   {
      for (int i = 2; i*i<= num; i++) {   
         if (num % i == 0) 
            return i;
      }

         /* ex:findSmallestFactor(8) -> 2
                findSmallestFactor(9) -> 3
                findSmallestFactor(7) -> 7
         */
      return -1;        //temporary return so program compiles
   }

   //post:  recursive method that places the prime factorization into myList
   //
   private static void generateList()
   {

         //generateList();
      int var = findNotPrime();
      if(var != -1){
         int n = findSmallestFactor(myList.get(var));
         myList.set(var, n);
         myList.add(myList.get(var)/n);
         generateList();
      }


   }
      /*    Hint:   Check the list to find the first non-prime factor.
            If all the numbers are prime, you are done.
            Otherwise,  * find the smallest factor of the first non-prime        and its cofactor.
                            * replace the first non-prime with its smallest factor and add the cofactor to the end
                            * repeat the whole process  */

   //post:  calcualtes the prime factorization of number and returns the list containing factors
   public static ArrayList<Integer> calculateFactors(int number)
   {
         /* place number in myList, generate the prime factorizations and return the list.*/
      myList.add(new Integer(number));
     //System.out.println(myList);
     generateList();
     return myList;
   }    

   public static void main(String[] arg)
   {
      System.out.println(8 + ":" + calculateFactors(8));
      myList.clear();
      System.out.println(60 + ":" + calculateFactors(60));
      myList.clear();
      System.out.println(75 + ":" + calculateFactors(75));
   }
}
```

The error code I get is

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

I have tested all the methods and they all seem to be working. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Do a little debugging. Find out which methods are being called. and how often, and decide if that's the behaviour you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you have figured out your task yet. But I did this task since it seemed like fun and since I've never done it before and.

What is the rules for answering a thread the asking person has solved already? Well.. it's easier to get forgiveness than permission...

The problem is mainly in generateList where you don't "save" a temp variable. This can be solved like this:

```
if(var != -1){
    int temp=myList.get(var);
    int n = findSmallestFactor(temp);
    myList.set(var, n);
    myList.add(temp/n);
    generateList();
}
```

Other than that you have to make a small change in isPrime method. For instance if you check if 2 is a prime it will say no, when in fact 2 is a prime number.

Answer (score 2):

You call `generateList` inside itself, causing an infinite recursion thus your stack overflows.